# Can we use md-autocomplete within an Angular app?

Tags: angular, angularjs-material

Fairly new to Angular2 and Angular in general.

Here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ it states:

> Developers should note that Angular Material v1 works only with
>   Angular 1.x.

Here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4844 it says:

we could use Angular 1 features within an Angular 2 app.

Hence, my doubts. Can anyone help?

Please note:
Since I'm fairly new, I wouldn't be able to test and see if the error is because of a non-supported feature atm, OR due to my lack of knowledge. Hence, the option for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look here [Material2](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for angular 2 it is under development, in future i think auto-complete will be there.

but check this article this may help you for now. http://4dev.tech/2016/03/tutorial-creating-an-angular2-autocomplete/, using this article you can also create your own angular2 auto-complete

Comment: thank you for your article suggestion. Nice finding! I will try it later.